# submit form to new tab in current pop-up

Tags: javascript, forms, tabs

A link in the main browser window opens up a report in a pop-up window using window.open(). On this report is a form to create a second report.

I want this form to submit to a new tab in the same window. But in Firefox it opens a new tab in the main browser window and in IE8 it opens in a new full-size browser window.

Can I force it to submit to a new tab in both?

thanks

Derek

Comment: Convert the form values to a query string and open new windows onclick with JavaScript.

Comment: How do you 'submit the form to a new window'?

Comment: the form values may contain a few K of text data so using a query string isn't practical